# redirecting to a .php page on submit of form else display alert

Tags: php

After user enters username and password and clicks on submit button(go)..a method in the database class(which is in temp.php),confirm() is called to check if username and password match.If matched 'tm.php' must load else an alert box must be displayed saying  username and password do not match!The alert box must be on first.php which is the page where user enters login info.
Code snippets:

temp.php:

```
class database{
function confirm($uname,$pwd){
//include('tm.php');

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hotels");
$res = $con->query("select * from user");
$row=$res->fetch_assoc();
$flag=0;
while($row)
{
if($row['username'] == $uname && $row['password'] == $pwd)
{$flag=1;
include('tm.php');
break;
}
$row=$res->fetch_assoc();
}
if($flag==1)?>
<script>alert("Username and Password do not match!");</script>
<?php
}
}
?>
}
```

first.php:

```
 <form action="first.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="pwd"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO">
    </form>

    <?php
    require('temp.php');

     if (isset($_POST['go']))
    {
    $db=new database();
    $uname=$_POST['uname'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
    $db->confirm($uname,$pwd);
    }
    ?>
```

The alert box does not appear nor does it get directed to tm.php.Please help me sort it out!

Comment: You can also try using Ajax. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: If i put an echo 'hello'; inside if(isset($_POST['go']))..it does not print at all.Does it mean that the isset part isnt being executed??

Comment: Yea. Do one thing. Remove that isset. And add all the contents of isset in temp.php. In the function itself. And then call the function from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
class database{
   function confirm($uname,$pwd){
   //include('tm.php');

   $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hotels");
   $res = $con->query("select * from user");
   $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
   $flag=0;
   while($row)
   {
       if($row['username'] == $uname && $row['password'] == $pwd)
       {
           $flag=1;
           include('tm.php');
           break;
       }
       $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
   }
   if($flag==1)
   {
       echo "<script>alert('Username and Password do not match!');</script>";
       header("refresh:0;url=first.php");
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class database{
function confirm($uname,$pwd){
//include('tm.php');

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hotels");
$res = $con->query("select * from user");
$row=$res->fetch_assoc();
$flag=0;
while($row)
{
   if($row['username'] == $uname && $row['password'] == $pwd)
   {
       $flag=1;
 // your include syntax was also wrong.
       include 'tm.php';

       break;
   }
   $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
}
// And here is your logical error. Changed it from 0 to 1. 
if($flag==0)
{
   echo "<script>alert('Username and Password do not match!');</script>";
   header("refresh:0;url=first.php");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It does not redirect to tm.php..the alert box also does not appear.@M.S.P

Comment: Change your require syntax to require_once 'temp.php';

Comment: I created another page,submit.php and wrote it in the form's action..retrieved variables from this page and passed to confirm method..That worked along with the header statement you suggested..Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. Pls do upvote my answer and consider marking it correct so that if in future, someone has a doubt similar to this, may also be helped.